# Deprecated pc-speaker option in Qemu

Tags: speakers, qemu

I'm trying to invoke Qemu from Linux, using the pc-speaker option, but when I do it, I get the following warning message:

`'-soundhw pcspk' is deprecated, please set a backend using '-machine pcspk-audiodev=<name>' instead`

what's the argument I should use for "name" here, in order to work properly in the new fashion?

I invoked Qemu with the following command line:

`qemu-system-x86_64 -drive if=pflash,format=raw,file=/usr/share/qemu/OVMF.fd -m 1900 -hda img.raw -device intel-hda -device hda-duplex -soundhw pcspk`

Answer (score 1):

What it is looking for is a sound sink to send the emulated PC speaker sounds to.

You can either enable the pc speaker driver in the linux kernel and use that or you can specify your machines sound card

```
-machine pcspk-audiodev=snd0
```

You will probably need to define an audio backend to use

So for me I need to do

```
-audiodev pa,id=snd0 -machine pcspk-audiodev=snd0
```

That routes PC speaker out my sound card using Pulse Audio. It also supports Jack for those who are so inclined.

I've had a look on my machine running PipeWire and the id's are longer strings (very long) but it seems to work

I used [this mailing list thread](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/qemu-discuss/2020-10/msg00031.html) and [this blog post](https://mathiashueber.com/virtual-machine-audio-setup-get-pulse-audio-working/) to create testing configs that appeared to work for me

Comment: Core audio is for Apple. If it can't init PA you might not have Pulse Audio installed?

I'm not a mind reader nor do I know exactly what you have installed.

Comment: Well, the option ```-audiodev coreaudio,id=audio0 -machine pcspk-audiodev=audio0``` from the GNU page doesn't work at all. It gives the warnings: ```audio: Unknown audio driver `coreaudio' | audio: warning: Using timer based audio emulation | audio: Device hda: audiodev default parameter is deprecated, please specify audiodev=audio0```.  
  
  Your suggestion didn't worked at all, and gave me the error: ```Could not init `pa' audio driver```